# ui-sref-active vs $state.includes()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here I'm trying to highlight the clicked area by adding active class using `ui-sref-active` and `$state.includes()`, but it's not working with `$state.includes()`, but I'm getting the value true when I see its value through the controller. Help me out.

Here's the code snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$state) {
$scope.res=$state.includes('')
});
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('page');
    $stateProvider
      .state('page', {
        url: '/page',
        template: "u clicked on Luffy"
      })
      .state('paper', {
        url: '/paper',
        template: "u clicked on Zoro"
      })

  })
```

```css
.active {
      background-color: red;
      color: white;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <hr>
    <h2>with ui-sref-active</h2>
    <button ui-sref-active=active ui-sref='page'>Luffy</button>
    <button ui-sref-active=active ui-sref='paper'>Zoro</button>
    <hr>
    <h2>with {'active':$state.includes('')}</h2>
    <button ng-class="{'active':$state.includes('page')}" ui-sref='page'>Luffy</button>
    <button ng-class="{'active':$state.includes('paper')}" ui-sref='paper'>Zoro</button>
    <hr> Result=
    <ui-view></ui-view>
    <hr>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$state` won't be accessible in HTML, you can call a function in controller to achieve this

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$state) {
  $scope.res = $state.includes('');
  $scope.checkActive = function(state) {
    return $state.includes(state)
  }
});
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('page');
    $stateProvider
      .state('page', {
        url: '/page',
        template: "u clicked on Luffy"
      })
      .state('paper', {
        url: '/paper',
        template: "u clicked on Zoro"
      })

  })
```

```css
.active {
      background-color: red;
      color: white;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <hr>
    <h2>with ui-sref-active</h2>
    <button ui-sref-active=active ui-sref='page'>Luffy</button>
    <button ui-sref-active=active ui-sref='paper'>Zoro</button>
    <hr>
    <h2>with {'active':$state.includes('')}</h2>
    <button ng-class="{'active':checkActive('page')}" ui-sref='page'>Luffy</button>
    <button ng-class="{'active':checkActive('paper')}" ui-sref='paper'>Zoro</button>
    <hr> Result=
    <ui-view></ui-view>
    <hr>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Or you could do `$scope.$state = $state` in the controller, but I like your code better as it only exposes all that it needs to to the view.

Comment: Thank you so much,i understood verywell now

Comment: @Abhishek np, glad it helped a bit :)